# Sublime text 3 breaks mercurial commit when applying changes to large file

Tags: mercurial, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, tortoisehg

I'm working on a 35k line file. If I add just 1 line anywhere in the file, my mercurial commit breaks. What happens is the following:

```
-someSuperCode(); // it shows me that the following two lines have been removed.
-int counter = 0;

+someSuperCode(); // And right beneath it, it show me that these two lines have been added.
+int counter = 0;
```

This happens for EVERY line in the file. These examples lines are not the ones I added but lines that were already in the file. I have tried every possible permutation of settings in sublime like add newline at end of file, translate tabs to spaces, remove white space on save but this always happens and I am now at the point that I have no clue what is happening. If I make the same changes in vim, everything works fine.

Comment: I guess, another problem caused by the most harmful invention ever, DOS line endings!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it was a problem with tortoise hg, I needed to set it to ignore whitespace. The weird thing is it still did not happen with vim.

Comment: It would be more useful if you post the exact cause and solution or just delete your question.